# Is it recommended to migrate everything to Riverpod or is it safe to use Riverpod and Provider together with Riverpod only for new features?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

We have already built a complex app implementing Provider as the state management solution.

Of course there are known limitations, Riverpod is now preferable but we are trying to understand if a full migration is necessary, or is it safe to continue in Riverpod for new features whilst keeping previous Provider implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there is no problem to use both solutions at the same time, because they are not connected.

You can slowly migrate toward Riverpod as needed, replacing dependencies time after time.

And yes, of course you can implement new features already using Riverpod.

Comment: Riverpod and Provider define many overlapping classes.  When I was migrating a client from provider to riverpod, I built a shim to rename all Provider classes to end in "X", and only then could I let them co-exist.

Comment: The question seemed to be whether `Riverpod` and `Provider` use common "business logic" through which they could harm each other. As far as I know, they don't and therefore can exist side by side. And the fact that you might need to use the `as` prefix on imports (and this kind of namespace division) is a different and trivial matter.

Comment: I beg to differ.  During my migration, I discovered that it was nearly impossible to go care-free back and forth in the dependency mesh between providers and riverpods.  To get the ecosystems to coexist took quite a few tricks.  And just "as" isn't enough.

Comment: Been doing a lot of work on it. Completely removing Provider and proceeding only on Riverpod is the only long term scalable solution. Whilst they can co-exist, it's painful